# How to instantiate a prefab at mouse location in the editor in unity?

Tags: unity, c#, unity-ui

I want to instantiate a prefab at the mouse position in the editor. All the answers I found till now are for instatiate a prefab at runtime but i want to **instantiate in the editor**.
Currently I am trying to use input.GetMouseButtonDown but that doesn't seem to work ?
Also is it fine to use raycasting in the editor itself?

**EDIT**: Alright I found that we need to use eventtype.MouseDown
but now the script is not executing?
there are no errors in the console window

````cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class mapMaker : Editor
{
    public GameObject rock;
    private void OnSceneGUI()
    {
        if (Event.current.type == EventType.MouseDown)
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.current.ScreenPointToRay(Event.current.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 1000.0f))
            {
                Debug.Log(Event.current.mousePosition);
                Vector3 newTilePosition = hit.point;
                Instantiate(rock, newTilePosition, Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }
    }
}

```
````

Comment: What have you tried so far? When you try using the runtime method at edit time, do the results differ from what you want in some way?

Comment: So is your problem with instantiating, as stated in your title, or with detecting mouse clicks, which isn't mentioned in your question at all? It looks like you should **edit your question** to describe in full what you've tried, including the script you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to listen to scene events.

Here is an example which creates an Editor Window which you can open from Window menu (in Unity menu bar). I think you can use pretty much the same code if you want to have similar functionality from a Custom Editor.

How to use: Open this window from Window menu (Raycast in editor test), then click 'Enable Raycasting' in Editor Window and click on some Collider in Scene View to spawn Default Cubes.

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class Raycast : EditorWindow
{
    static bool active;

    // Open this from Window menu
    [MenuItem("Window/Raycast in editor test")]
    static void Init()
    {
        var window = (Raycast)EditorWindow.GetWindow(typeof(Raycast));
        window.Show();
    }

    // Listen to scene event
    void OnEnable() => SceneView.duringSceneGui += OnSceneGUI;
    void OnDisable() => SceneView.duringSceneGui -= OnSceneGUI;

    // Receives scene events
    // Use event mouse click for raycasting
    void OnSceneGUI(SceneView view)
    {
        if (!active)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (Event.current.type == EventType.MouseDown)
        {
            Ray ray = HandleUtility.GUIPointToWorldRay(Event.current.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;

            // Spawn cube on hit location
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                Debug.Log("Hit: " + hit.collider.gameObject.name);

                var obj = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
                obj.transform.position = hit.point;
            }
        }

        Event.current.Use();
    }

    // Creates a editor window with button 
    // to toggle raycasting on/off
    void OnGUI()
    {
        if (GUILayout.Button("Enable Raycasting"))
        {
            active = !active;
        }

        GUILayout.Label("Active:" + active);
    }

}
```